# Is it necessary to include sites-enabled directory within nginx.conf?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am following [Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) tutorial. I was stuck on part [Configure nginx for your site](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site). I tried everything that I have found searching the internet, mainly I was trying to fix my config `mysite_nginx.conf` file, but it seems now that it was correct all the time.

This is my config file `mysite_nginx.conf` which of course is symlinked from `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen                8000;
    server_name           localhost;
    charset               utf-8;
    client_max_body_size  75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /Users/username/dev/my_site/mysite/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /Users/username/dev/my_site/mysite/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /Users/username/dev/my_site/mysite/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

#### The problem I faced

Visiting `localhost:8000/media/img.jpg` or `localhost:8000/static/img.jpg` always was returning `404 Not Found`. In nginx logs all of the requests were mapped to `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/version/html/` which is a symlink to the `/usr/local/var/www/` where `index.html` and `5xx.html` files are present.

My `static/` and `media/` were added to the `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/version/html/` so in nginx error logs I saw requests to `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/version/html/static/img.jpg`.

#### The solution that worked for me

In `nginx.conf` file I have included path to the sites-enabled. After this all of my requests where mapped to the absolute paths that I have added as an alias of the location and everything worked as expected.

```
...

http {
    include       mime.types;
    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

...
```

#### The Question

In the tutorial that I mentioned there was no mention about this, so I suppose it should work without editing `nginx.conf` file? But it didn't worked for me, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no restriction or necessity to follow one approach. You can have all your config in a single `nginx.conf` or you can split it into multiple files and include them, or you can include specific patterns from a directory.

Different OS distribution may use different config type of default config setup. The common one being usage of a `nginx.conf` using `include site-enabled/*.conf;` and `include conf-enabled/*.conf;`

The logic is that your create your actual config in `sites-available` and `conf-available` directory and you just symlink them in the `sites-enabled` and `conf-enabled` directory respectively. So tomorrow if you want to disable a config then instead of renaming or deleting it you just delete the symlink from `xxxx-enabled` directory. This is just a convention so it easier for you to manage virtual hosts related to different sites in their own files.

By default these have some default configs which are for the demo nginx page. Before setting up your config you should disable this, so that it doesn't mess up with your config.

Now sometimes the include may not be part of the default `nginx.conf`. Because you installed nginx using brew the config used in that installation is different. If you check the file it has below include

```
include servers/*;
```

So the expectation is to put it at different place. So you have to be aware that the base config is `nginx.conf` (that also can be changed by compiling nginx from source). It can then include other configs or choose not to and just have a default server in `nginx.conf` itself. Before following any tutorial do read your `nginx.conf` file first.